# PDF not created after compilation

Tags: output

Suddenly when I compile the latex document a PDF file is not generated. I have no errors, and the only change from the last time when everything was OK is that my laptop restarted itself.

Is there any ideas what the problem can be ??

The log file contents:

```
 This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930 64-bit) (preloaded format=latex 2019.1.17)  22 JAN 2019 22:05
entering extended mode
**./main.tex
(main.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\report.cls"
Document Class: report 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
... 
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/siunitx\siunitx.sty"
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty"
Package: expl3 2019-01-01 L3 programming layer (loader) 

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
Package: expl3 2019-01-01 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count89
...
...
\l__seq_internal_b_int=\count172
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\l3dvips.def"
File: l3dvips.def 2019-01-01 v L3 Experimental driver: dvips
\g__driver_pdf_object_int=\count173
))
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty"
Package: xparse 2018-10-17 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count174
...
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count178
)
Package: siunitx 2018/05/17 v2.7s A comprehensive (SI) units package

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\ex@=\dimen135
))
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\array.sty"
Package: array 2018/11/13 v2.4j Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen136
...
\ar@cellbox=\box43
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e\l3keys2e.sty"
Package: l3keys2e 2018-10-17 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
\l__siunitx_tmp_box=\box44
 ... 
\l__siunitx_table_text_align_skip=\skip54

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/translator\translator.sty"
Package: translator 2018/01/04 v1.12 Easy translation of strings in LaTeX

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)))
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/lm\lmodern.sty"
Package: lmodern 2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
....
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks17
\inpenc@posthook=\toks18
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 99.

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\dvips.def"
File: dvips.def 2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen150
\Gin@req@width=\dimen151
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/caption\caption.sty"
Package: caption 2018/10/06 v3.3-154 Customizing captions (AR)

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/caption\caption3.sty"
Package: caption3 2018/09/12 v1.8c caption3 kernel (AR)
Package caption3 Info: TeX engine: e-TeX on input line 64.
\captionmargin=\dimen152
...
\caption@hangindent=\dimen158
)
\c@caption@flags=\count196
\c@ContinuedFloat=\count197
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\indentfirst.sty"
Package: indentfirst 1995/11/23 v1.03 Indent first paragraph (DPC)
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/setspace\setspace.sty"
Package: setspace 2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/comment\comment.sty"
\CommentStream=\write3
 Excluding comment 'comment')
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2018/12/01 v2.17b AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip55

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen159
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count198
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 223.
\uproot@=\count199
\leftroot@=\count266
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 385.
\classnum@=\count267
\DOTSCASE@=\count268
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 482.
...
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2845.
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ms\ragged2e.sty"
Package: ragged2e 2009/05/21 v2.1 ragged2e Package (MS)

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ms\everysel.sty"
Package: everysel 2011/10/28 v1.2 EverySelectfont Package (MS)
)
\CenteringLeftskip=\skip58
...
...
\JustifyingParindent=\skip71
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/titlesec\titlesec.sty"
Package: titlesec 2016/03/21 v2.10.2 Sectioning titles
\ttl@box=\box53
...
\titlewidthfirst=\dimen171
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\tabularx.sty"
Package: tabularx 2016/02/03 v2.11b `tabularx' package (DPC)
\TX@col@width=\dimen172
...
\TX@ftn=\toks24
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/jknappen\mathrsfs.sty"
Package: mathrsfs 1996/01/01 Math RSFS package v1.0 (jk)
\symrsfs=\mathgroup6
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty"
Package: geometry 2018/04/16 v5.8 Page Geometry

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifvtex.sty"
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count277
...
\Gm@dimlist=\toks25

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty"
Package: fancyhdr 2017/06/30 v3.9a Extensive control of page headers and footers
\f@nch@headwidth=\skip74
...
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip82
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/was\fixmath.sty"
Package: fixmath 2000/04/11 v0.9 (WaS)
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 28.
...
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varsigma on input line 66.
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex\biblatex.sty"
Package: biblatex 2018/11/02 v3.12 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2018/09/10 v0.29 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
...
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode is ignored in DVI mode.
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty"
Package: etoolbox 2018/08/19 v2.5f e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count280
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)))
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/logreq\logreq.sty"
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count281

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/logreq\logreq.def"
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
))
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty"
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip17
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count282
...
... 
\c@mincompwidth=\count325
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex\blx-dm.def"
File: blx-dm.def 2018/11/02 v3.12 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex style data model...
...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-bibtex.def' found.

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex\blx-bibtex.def"
File: blx-bibtex.def 2018/11/02 v3.12 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)


Package biblatex Warning: Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:
(biblatex)                functionality may be reduced/unavailable.

)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.
 ("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex\biblatex.def"
File: biblatex.def 2018/11/02 v3.12 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
\c@textcitecount=\count394
...
\c@smartand=\count400
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric-comp'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric-comp.bbx' found.

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/bbx\numeric-comp.bbx"
File: numeric-comp.bbx 2018/11/02 v3.12 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.bbx' found.

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/bbx\numeric.bbx"
File: numeric.bbx 2018/11/02 v3.12 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/bbx\standard.bbx"
File: standard.bbx 2018/11/02 v3.12 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count401
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count402
)))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'numeric-comp'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric-comp.cbx' found.

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/cbx\numeric-comp.cbx"
File: numeric-comp.cbx 2018/11/02 v3.12 biblatex citation style (PK/MW)
\c@cbx@tempcnta=\count403
\c@cbx@tempcntb=\count404
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
...
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex\biblatex.cfg"
File: biblatex.cfg 
))
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/nomencl\nomencl.sty"
Package: nomencl 2018/12/29 v5.0 Nomenclature package

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks26
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks27
)
\XKV@depth=\count405
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\nomlabelwidth=\dimen185
\nom@tempdim=\dimen186
\nomitemsep=\skip105
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/lbx\english.lbx"
File: english.lbx 2018/11/02 v3.12 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
\@quotelevel=\count406
\@quotereset=\count407
 (main.aux)
\openout1 = `main.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 99.
...
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+lmr on input line 99.

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/lm\ot1lmr.fd"
File: ot1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
Now handling font encoding TS1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding TS1

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ts1enc.dfu"
File: ts1enc.dfu 2018/10/05 v1.2f UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A2 (decimal 162)
   ...
   defining Unicode char U+FEFF (decimal 65279)
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/translator\translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict"
Dictionary: translator-basic-dictionary, Language: English 
)
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/siunitx\siunitx-abbreviations.cfg"
File: siunitx-abbreviations.cfg 2017/11/26 v2.7k siunitx: Abbreviated units
)
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.

ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros
LaTeX Info: Redefining \selectfont on input line 99.

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: dvips
* paper: a4paper
...
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

Package biblatex Info: Input encoding 'utf8' detected.
...
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 99.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OML+lmm on input line 99.
 ("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/lm\omllmm.fd"
File: omllmm.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+lmsy on input line 99.

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/lm\omslmsy.fd"
File: omslmsy.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMX+lmex on input line 99.

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/lm\omxlmex.fd"
File: omxlmex.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 99.
...
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+lmtt on input line 99.

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/lm\ot1lmtt.fd"
File: ot1lmtt.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
\@nomenclaturefile=\write5
\openout5 = `main.nlo'.

Package nomencl Info: Writing nomenclature file main.nlo on input line 117.
 (chapters/abstract.tex [1

]) [2]
(chapters/acknowledgments.tex [3

]) [4] (main.toc [5

])
\tf@toc=\write6
\openout6 = `main.toc'.
 (main.nls [6] [7
] [8] [9] [10]) [11] (main.lot)
\tf@lot=\write7
\openout7 = `main.lot'.
 [12    
] (main.lof
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []
 [13
])
\tf@lof=\write8
\openout8 = `main.lof'.
 [14]
Chapter 1.
(chapters/introduction.tex
Underfull \vbox (badness 6708) has occurred while \output is active []
 [1
] [2]
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+lmr on input line 86.
("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/lm\omslmr.fd"
File: omslmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OMS/lmr/m/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OMS/lmsy/m/n' tried instead on input line 86.
 [3] [4]
File: images/parallelRayProjectionsMatlab.eps Graphic file (type eps)

<images/parallelRayProjectionsMatlab.eps> [5]
File: images/setupImage.eps Graphic file (type eps)
 <images/setupImage.eps>
LaTeX Warning: `h' float specifier changed to `ht'.
[6]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []
 [7]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []
 [8]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []
 [9]) [10]
Chapter 2.
(chapters/chapter02.tex
Underfull \vbox (badness 2269) has occurred while \output is active []
 [11
]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []
 [12]
File: images/potential_of_bound_electron_in_laser_field.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<images/potential_of_bound_electron_in_laser_field.eps>
Underfull \vbox (badness 3735) has occurred while \output is active []
 [13] [14] [15] [16]
Underfull \vbox (badness 2799) has occurred while \output is active []
 [17]
File: images/Keldysh_parameter_regimes_2.eps Graphic file (type eps)
 <images/Keldysh_parameter_regimes_2.eps>

LaTeX Warning: `h' float specifier changed to `ht'.


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [18] [19]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [20]
Underfull \vbox (badness 5133) has occurred while \output is active []

 [21] [22] [23] [24] [25]
Underfull \vbox (badness 1354) has occurred while \output is active []

 [26]
Underfull \vbox (badness 3000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [27] [28]
Underfull \vbox (badness 3503) has occurred while \output is active []

 [29] [30]
Underfull \vbox (badness 2809) has occurred while \output is active []

 [31] [32]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [33] [34]
File: images/harmonicFullSpectrumAtDensestJetPointShortScan4_5bar.eps Graphic file (type eps)

<images/harmonicFullSpectrumAtDensestJetPointShortScan4_5bar.eps>) [35]
Chapter 3.
(chapters/chapter03.tex [36

]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [37]
Underfull \vbox (badness 1237) has occurred while \output is active []

 [38]
File: images/FourierSliceTheorem.eps Graphic file (type eps)
 <images/FourierSliceTheorem.eps>

LaTeX Warning: `h' float specifier changed to `ht'.


Underfull \vbox (badness 2221) has occurred while \output is active []

 [39]
File: images/frequencyRadialLines.eps Graphic file (type eps)
 <images/frequencyRadialLines.eps> [40] [41]
[42] [43]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [44]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [45]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [46]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [47]
Underfull \vbox (badness 2343) has occurred while \output is active []

 [48]
Underfull \vbox (badness 7576) has occurred while \output is active []

 [49] [50] [51])
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [52] [53]
Chapter 4.
(chapters/chapter04.tex [54

]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [55]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [56]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [57]
Overfull \hbox (0.65761pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 125--135
\OT1/lmr/m/n/12 elec-tric field. The fre-quency de-pen-dent $\OML/lmm/m/it/12 n$\OT1/lmr/m/n/12 -th or-der sus-cep-ti-bi
l-ity $\OML/lmm/m/it/12 []\OT1/lmr/m/n/12 (\OML/lmm/m/it/12 !\OT1/lmr/m/n/12 ; \OML/lmm/m/it/12 ![]; ![]; :::; ![]\OT1/
lmr/m/n/12 )$
 []


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [58]
Underfull \vbox (badness 1365) has occurred while \output is active []

 [59] [60] [61]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [62]
File: images/1PF_versus_2PF.eps Graphic file (type eps)
 <images/1PF_versus_2PF.eps> [63] [64]
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+lmr on input line 364.

("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/lm\ts1lmr.fd"
File: ts1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
) [65]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [66]
Underfull \vbox (badness 6961) has occurred while \output is active []

 [67]
File: images/f_2a.eps Graphic file (type eps)
 <images/f_2a.eps>
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in alignment at lines 468--468
[][] 
 []


LaTeX Warning: `h' float specifier changed to `ht'.

[68]
File: images/f_2b.eps Graphic file (type eps)
 <images/f_2b.eps>

LaTeX Warning: `h' float specifier changed to `ht'.


Underfull \vbox (badness 1142) has occurred while \output is active []

 [69]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [70]
File: images/f_2c.eps Graphic file (type eps)
 <images/f_2c.eps>
Overfull \hbox (0.94571pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 516--519
 []|  [] 
 []

[71]
File: images/f_2d.eps Graphic file (type eps)
 <images/f_2d.eps> [72]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [73] [74] [75] [76]
File: images/projection_of_jet_slice_of_0_9_mm_below_nozzle.eps Graphic file (type eps)

<images/projection_of_jet_slice_of_0_9_mm_below_nozzle.eps>
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [77]

LaTeX Warning: `h' float specifier changed to `ht'.


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [78] [79]
File: images/jet_slice.eps Graphic file (type eps)
 <images/jet_slice.eps>
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [80]
Underfull \vbox (badness 1466) has occurred while \output is active []

 [81]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [82]
File: images/theoretical_density.eps Graphic file (type eps)
 <images/theoretical_density.eps>
Overfull \hbox (1.11208pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 810--812
 [] 
 []

)
Underfull \vbox (badness 3260) has occurred while \output is active []

 [83] [84]
Chapter 5.
(chapters/chapter05.tex
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [85

] [86]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [87]) [88]
Overfull \hbox (8.02007pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 194--194
[]\OT1/lmr/m/n/12 J Itatani et al. ``To-mo-graphic imag-ing of molec-u-lar or-bitals''. In: \OT1/lmr/m/it/12 Na-ture \OT
1/lmr/m/n/12 432.7019
 []

[89


]
Overfull \hbox (12.29187pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 194--194
\OT1/lmr/m/n/12 Order Har-monic Gen-er-a-tion''. In: \OT1/lmr/m/it/12 Phys-i-cal re-view let-ters \OT1/lmr/m/n/12 115.13
 (2015), p. 133901. 
 []

[90]
Overfull \hbox (1.45865pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 194--194
[]\OT1/lmr/m/n/12 AC Kak and M Slaney. \OT1/lmr/m/it/12 Prin-ci-ples of com-put-er-ized to-mo-graphic imag-ing\OT1/lmr/m
/n/12 . SIAM,
 []

[91] [92] [93]
Overfull \hbox (3.77711pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 194--194
[]\OT1/lmr/m/n/12 RN Bracewell. \OT1/lmr/m/it/12 The Fourier trans-form and its ap-pli-ca-tions\OT1/lmr/m/n/12 . Vol. 31
999. McGraw-
 []

[94]
Overfull \hbox (2.10953pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 194--194
\OT1/lmr/m/n/12 scope''. In: \OT1/lmr/m/it/12 Op-tica Acta: In-ter-na-tional Jour-nal of Op-tics \OT1/lmr/m/n/12 24.10 (
1977), pp. 1051{
 []

[95]
Overfull \hbox (8.80801pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 194--194
[]\OT1/lmr/m/n/12 YR Shen. ``The prin-ci-ples of non-lin-ear op-tics''. In: \OT1/lmr/m/it/12 New York, Wiley-Interscienc
e,
 []

[96]
Overfull \hbox (0.40848pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 194--194
[]\OT1/lmr/m/n/12 A. Mod-ena et al. ``Elec-tron ac-cel-er-a-tion from the break-ing of rel-a-tivis-tic plasma
 []

[97] [98


] (main.aux)
Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'main.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `main.run.xml'.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 23432 strings out of 492947
 465938 string characters out of 3126292
 837947 words of memory out of 3000000
 27038 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 595328 words of font info for 76 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 40i,23n,77p,2755b,1533s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on main.dvi (112 pages, 306844 bytes).
```

Comment: What does the log file say?

Comment: Show the log-file.

Comment: It's a long file. I copied to the question the beginning of it. Does it tell something useful?

Comment: I copied most of the log file to the question window. I cannot copy all of it since it's too long. The lines I deleted from the log file are the ones with the '...' sign.  I'm using TeXnicCenter editor.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of the log says:

```
 preloaded format=latex 2019.1.17
```

The last line says

```
 Output written on main.dvi (112 pages, 306844 bytes).
```

This means you are creating a dvi, not a pdf. So you probably clicked on the wrong button in your editor (latex instead of pdflatex).

Comment: It doesn't seem so. The selected output profile is still: 'Latex->PS->PDF->nomencl' , just as was before the problem. To compile I only choose the build option.

Comment: Why are you using the latex-ps-route instead of directly pdflatex? Debugging ps-pdf is more difficult as there are more steps.

Comment: I think I had to choose this route becuse it was the only one that produced the eps images correctly on the document.

Comment: pdflatex handles eps fine (it converts them on the fly), and even in case of problems it is easier to convert the eps manually once than to use the ps-pdf route. If you want to stick to ps-pdf you will have to call dvips and ps2pdf once on the command line to get sensible error messages.

Comment: Via that route there are two paths A) DVIPS B) Ghostscript PS2PDF can you confirm which one you used in profile as it could help to look at potential failings

Comment: How can I know which of the two paths I used?  I'm not a knowledgable user of TeX. Can you tell me please how to verify that point step by step?

Comment: latex-ps-pdf is quite probably dvips and then ps2pdf. The configuration of your editor can tell you it more in detail. But I would really advise you to switch to pdflatex. At least try is out. The worst that can happen is that you get some error.

Comment: Regarding the command line with the call to 'dvips' and 'ps2pdf' - can you tell me please what exactly should I do step by step?

Comment: Go in the windows explorer to the folder of your document. Type in the address field `cmd` and hit enter, this should open a command line. Type there `dvips main` and hit enter, if it produce a ps, type `ps2pdf main` and hit enter.

Comment: to check current setting in TeXnicCenter press Alt+F7 highlight latex>ps>pdf then select postprocessor it is likely highlighting first choice in grey Dvi (PDF) and the executable should end with …\MiKTeX\bin\dvips.exe AVOID changing but the other if shown should be the current ghostscript if its installed